# Indefinite number of tables vs indefinite number of row with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle, database-design

Which one would be better (performance wise and maintenance), a database which creates table dynamically or just adding rows dynamically?

Suppose I am building a project in which I let users to register. Say I have a table which store only basic personal infos, like name, dob, Date of joining, address, phone, etc. Say 10 columns.

Now is the tricky part.

**Scene 1: Creating multiple tables**

When a user complete registration, a message table is created. So each table is created for each users. The rows of each message table varies for each user.

In the same way there is a cart table for each user like the message table.

For this scene 1, 2 tables are created with every registration.

**Scene 2: Adding Rows**

The scenario is same here as well, but in this case I have 2 tables for message and cart. Rows are added only when there is an activity.

**Note:**

You must assume that the number of users is more than 2000 and expect 50+ users to be active all the time. Which means the message and cart tables are always busy for both the cases. Like there is always a query for update, add, delete, insert, select etc. simultaneously.

Also which scene will consume more disk space.

While writing this, it make me wonder what technique would Facebook and others use. If they use the Scene 2 style (all users (billions) use the same big long message table)... Just wondering

Comment: I think that creating one table for every user is madness, you'll create tables for every user independently if they are active or not. And between a scenario where you need to choose either a billion tables or one table with a billion rows, the last one is obviously the one that most database engines are made for

Comment: So searching the rows will be easier than searching the table. Thank you

Comment: Picture a scenario where you want to query for messages that have only been generated by a subset of users. This would be much easier to achieve with just one table for all users. In fact, it would be quite horrible the other way around.

Comment: If I were you, I would not start building a database from scratch without reading a few papers about normal forms, primary keys, foreign keys, referential integrity, etc.

Comment: More to the point, you need to learn what a Relational database is. i.e. tables are not just a dump for data, they *mean* something. Look up articles by Chris J. Date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Databases has some basic rules defined for Database Design called
>   "Database Normalization", These basic rules allow us eliminating
>   redundant data.
>
> **1st Normal Form** 
>   Store One piece of information in only One Column, A column should store only One piece of information.
>
> **2ns Normal Form** 
>   A Table should have only the columns that are related to each other. All the related columns should be in One table.
>
> Now if you look at your advised design, A Separate Table for each USER
>   will split SAME information/Columns about all the user in 1000's of
>   tables. Which violates the 2nd Normal Form.
>
> You need to Create One Table and put all the related Columns in that
>   one table for all the users. and you can make use of normal t-sql to
>   query your data but if you have a table for each user my guess is your
>   every query that you execute from your application will be built
>   dynamically and for every query you will be using dynamic sql. which
>   is one of the Sql Devils and you want to avoid using it whenever
>   possible.
>
> My suggestion would be read more about Database Design. Once you have
>   some basic understanding of database design. Draw it on a piece of
>   paper and see if it provides you everything that your business
>   requires / expects from this application , Spend sometime on it now it
>   will save you a lot of pain later.

Comment: ouf ... I was getting nervous just reading the question! I am happy you supplied an answer.

Comment: my pleasure took me whole 7 minutes to write it and format it :)